# Node - webpack: Failed to compile

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

Doing a react tutorial

```
npm start
```

allows the application page to be displayed in the browser at localhost:8080

but keeps showing error in the terminal console:

```
webpack: Compiling...

ERROR in this is not a typed array.
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":

webpack: Failed to compile.
```

Node `v4.6.2`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that one option is to upgrade from node 4.2.6 to node 6.0.0

Results in:

$ npm start

```
> react-speed-book@1.0.0 start /home/durrantm/Dropbox/92_2017/work/code/javascript/react/react_speed_book/react-speed-book
> NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --inline

 http://localhost:8080/
webpack result is served from /
content is served from /home/durrantm/Dropbox/92_2017/work/code/javascript/react/react_speed_book/react-speed-book
404s will fallback to /index.html
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":

webpack: Compiled successfully.
```